# Zend replacement in 2.4.6

Tags: laminas, zend, magento2.4.6

I have a theme and extensions that use widely the Zend_Json function
i.e.for example :
window.checkout = getConfig()); ?>;
in 2.4.5 I had no problem using this code, in 2.4.6 it throws an exception :
" main.CRITICAL: Error: Class "Zend_Json" not found in"
I have the laminas package...what can go wrong ?
TIA for help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Zend usage deprecated since 2.4.6
Now you can use Laminas.
Usage: replace `Zend_Json` with `\Laminas\Json\Json`
Be sure that you have installed `laminas/laminas-serializer`

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me. Changed instances of \Zend_Json to \Laminas\Json\Json

Comment: Please avoid this lib to avoid future incompatibility issue. And it does not needed, because Magento has own class to work with Json in native Magento way. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I. Magento 2.4.6 doesn't require `laminas/laminas-serializer` out-of-the-box. It requires `laminas/laminas-json`.
You can use `laminas/laminas-json`.

II.
But
there is a more **proper way**:

```php
\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->serialize()
\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->unserialize()
```

just to add object in your __construct().

```php
    public function __construct(
        private readonly \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $jsonSerializer
    ) {
        $string = $this->jsonSerializer->serialize(['data' => 'to_encode']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like following

```
Magento 2.4.3
\Zend_Json::decode($infoRequestOption->getData('value'),true);

Magento 2.4.6
\Laminas\Json\Json::decode($infoRequestOption->getData('value'),true);
```